# Creating SAML response from SAML request using saml2-js library

Tags: node.js, saml, saml-2.0

I'm using saml2-js library for both IdP and service provider.
The library provides me a redirecting and a samlRequest token, but unfortunately I didn't succeed to create the SAML response. Currently I have the user details and the SAML request token. The library suggests an assert function, but I can use it only after a SAML response is created.

My config file looks like:

```
const sp_options = {
    entity_id: `${SP_SERVER}/metadata.xml`,
    private_key: fs.readFileSync("certs/saml.pem").toString(),
    certificate: fs.readFileSync("certs/saml.crt").toString(),
    assert_endpoint: `${SP_SERVER}/assert`
};

// Create identity provider
const idp_options = {
    sso_login_url: IDP_PAGE,
    sso_logout_url: `${IDP_PAGE}/logout`,
    certificate: fs.readFileSync("certs/saml.crt").toString(),
};

const sp = new saml2.ServiceProvider(sp_options);
const idp = new saml2.IdentityProvider(idp_options);
```

Comment: This library I don't think does what you want it to do - it is really only meant to represent SP actions; it has an Identity Provider object but it's really just to represent IdP metadata.